# QC 11.5 OTA API's script run

Tags: hp-quality-center

I have problem in running working script (OTA API's) written for QC 10.0 on QC 11.5. I am not able to login in 11.5 through API's, i heard that v11.5 needs some client registration to be done to run the API's script. Could anybody tell me if you have faced same issue. Thank you.

i am getting the error: Unable to connect to QC.

The key points i have known from my research is that:

1. In QC 10.0 client registation used to happen by defualt, so API was running by default without any additional set up.
2. QC 11.5 client registration is not default, so it is stopping API's script to run on it.

The questions now i have how to do this client registration and all. And is it really necessary, can't i run the script directly or do registration on my own.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to set up client registration. And these are the main points:

QC 10.0 does not require client registration to be done seperately, we login to QC 10.0 by opening browser as an admin, so this helps QC to register automatically.

QC 11.5 does not register client on its own, user has to do it seperately by clicking register link in addins page. Only then user can run API's scripts.

Now i am able to register the client and run my script on QC 11.5.

Let me know if anyone needs any help on this.